# Движение объекта(Left, Right)

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать что б если например мышку подвинули влево, объект тоже передвинулся влево, если в право то вправо. Вот код<br>
**html**

```
   <div id="bottom">
       <div id="inv"></div>
    </div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var xPrev = 0;

    $("#bottom").mousemove(function(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX;

        xPrev<e.pageX ? $("#inv").animate({
            marginLeft: '+=50'
        }) :  $("#inv").animate({
            marginRight: '+=50'
        });

        xPrev=e.pageX;

        console.log(xPrev);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется будет достаточно этого:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('div').css({'left':e.pageX , 'top':e.pageY});
});
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/xw98x/2/